# PHP upload multiple files with different input field names

Tags: php

Trying to upload multiple files have different input names. Since I need only 1 insert query I need to upload them in an array I think. I need to insert file names to different columns in the same row

```
if(isset($_FILES['MainImage'])){
  $main_image_name = $_FILES['MainImage']['name'];
  $main_image_size = $_FILES['MainImage']['size'];
  $main_image_tmp = $_FILES['MainImage']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadMainTo = $uploadLocation.$main_image_name;
  $moveMain = move_uploaded_file($main_image_tmp,$uploadMainTo);

}

if(isset($_FILES['PDF'])){
  $pdf_name = $_FILES['PDF']['name'];
  $pdf_size = $_FILES['PDF']['size'];
  $pdf_tmp = $_FILES['PDF']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadPdfTo = $uploadLocation.$pdf_name;
  $movepdf = move_uploaded_file($pdf_tmp,$uploadPdfTo);
}
```

My form looks like:

```
<input type="file" name="PDF">
<input type="file" name="MainImage">
```

Query:

```
$query = $db->execute("INSERT INTO users (pdf=?, main_image=?) VALUES (?,?) WHERE ID=$user_id", array($pdf, $main_image) );
```

Comment: You need only 2 files (1 PDF and 1 MainImage) or multiple (N PDFs and N MainImages)?

Comment: I need to insert 2 images (2 input fields) and 1 pdf file at the same time.

Comment: If you need help with your SQL Query too, please provide us some DB information and the query you have build so far...

Comment: Just updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in your comment:

> I need to insert 2 images (2 input fields) and 1 pdf file at the same time

So, I assume that you will have all the file inputs in your HTML markup, something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="PDF">
<input type="file" name="MainImage">
<input type="file" name="SecondImage">
```

In this case, to insert the file path of the uploaded file to the database, something like this should work:

```
$uploadMainTo = null;
if(isset($_FILES['MainImage'])){
  $main_image_name = $_FILES['MainImage']['name'];
  $main_image_size = $_FILES['MainImage']['size'];
  $main_image_tmp = $_FILES['MainImage']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadMainTo = $uploadLocation.$main_image_name;
  $moveMain = move_uploaded_file($main_image_tmp,$uploadMainTo);
}

$uploadSecondTo = null;
if(isset($_FILES['SecondImage'])){
  $second_image_name = $_FILES['SecondImage']['name'];
  $second_image_size = $_FILES['SecondImage']['size'];
  $second_image_tmp = $_FILES['SecondImage']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadSecondTo = $uploadLocation.$second_image_name;
  $moveSecond = move_uploaded_file($second_image_tmp,$uploadSecondTo);
}

$uploadPdfTo = null;
if(isset($_FILES['PDF'])){
  $pdf_name = $_FILES['PDF']['name'];
  $pdf_size = $_FILES['PDF']['size'];
  $pdf_tmp = $_FILES['PDF']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadPdfTo = $uploadLocation.$pdf_name;
  $movepdf = move_uploaded_file($pdf_tmp,$uploadPdfTo);
}

$query = $db->execute("INSERT INTO users (pdf, main_image, second_image) VALUES (?,?,?) WHERE ID = ?", array($uploadPdfTo, $uploadMainTo, $uploadSecondTo, $user_id) );
```

I'm just not sure if i have to initialize the `$uploadXTo` variables with `null` or `'NULL'`. If you have problems please test this way.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly correct your html

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
```

then you can use php array

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][0]
$_FILES['userfile']['size'][0]
$_FILES['userfile']['type'][0]
```

Check the php docs: [Uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: What if I need to insert file names to different colomns in the same row in my database?

Comment: it's simple, $_FILES['userfile']['name'][0] is name of first file, and $_FILES['userfile']['name'][1] second file name

Comment: @Jawlon Rodriguez, can we use your php code with foreach loop

Comment: @user123 Yes you can.

Comment: @Jawlon Rodriguez, can you please update your answer with foreach?